# Merge duplicate values from array in Json Formate

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am fetching data from location MySql table as structure is below
in my PHP code

[image]

I need send Json output in response as below  (Table data may not be same as below json data but the format is same)

```
 http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=7c5600712df6f9ec1f8fbb8a13aba3de
```

Tried to do the following in the code to convert the array that i fetch from the table but however am unable to get it in the right format

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM mobile_user_regions";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resCArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$ress = array();

foreach ($resCArray as $key => $value) {

    $ress['regions'][] = array(array(
            'name' => $value['region'],
            'location' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => $value['location'],
                    'store' => array(
                        'store_details' => $value['store_details'],
                        'store_phone' => $value['store_phone'],
                        'store_email' => $value['store_email'],
                        'store_latitude' => $value['store_latitude'],
                        'store_longitude' => $value['store_longitude']
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );


 Output: that i am getting is 
 **http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=4d4a75177350e254ceee7238af13f2f7**
```

Comment: what problem or error are you getting?

Comment: can you show the format what you are making

Comment: Output that i am getting is 
 http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=4d4a75177350e254ceee7238af13f2f7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$regionArray = $xyzObject->getRegion();
if (!empty($regionArray) && isset($regionArray)) {
    $i = 0;
    $locationData = array();
    foreach ($regionArray as $key => $value) {
        $locationData['regions'][$i]['name'] = $value['region'];

        $locationArray = $xyzObject->getLocation($value['region']);
        $locationData['regions'][$i]['locations'] = $locationArray;
        $i++;
    }
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($locationData['regions'] as $key => $regions) {
        $k = 0;
        foreach ($regions['locations'] as $key1 => $locations) {

            $storeArray = $xyzObject->getStore($locations['name']);
            $locationData['regions'][$j]['locations'][$k]['stores'] = $storeArray;
            $k++;
        }
        $j++;
    }
    echo json_encode($locationData);
```